# how to find missing component in pcb using feature matching in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project where I have to find a missing component on a PCB.
I have tested with image subtraction, but my lighting conditions are not good and images are not of the same orientation.
As a result, I am trying to solve this with feature matching. However I am not able to detect each and every component. Also am not able to locate the position of the missing component properly.

How I should proceed further?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('./pcb_images/frame_51.png')
img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (640, 480))

img2 = cv2.imread('./pcb_images/frame_56.png')
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (640, 480))

orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
#print(kp1)
#print(kp2)
img_kp = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2, kp2, 0, color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
cv2.imshow("img_kp",img_kp)
# matcher takes normType, which is set to cv2.NORM_L2 for SIFT        and SURF, cv2.NORM_HAMMING for ORB, FAST and BRIEF
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
#print(bf)
matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)# draw first 50 matches
#print(matches)


 match_img = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[:20], None)
 cv2.imshow('Matches', match_img)
 cv2.waitKey()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[[image: ![]original image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zi0U.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zi0U.png)
[[image: defected image3]

Comment: Once you have matches, you can do warpPerspective() to align the images, then do your subtraction. See for example https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html and also https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Comment: through image matching it is working but i am not getting proper output as original PCB has 19 component and defected PCB has 17 so how would i proceed further

Comment: I want only the component features to be detected.... not other things

Comment: Can you please suggest me best method to do this task...

Comment: I want to detect location of unmatched feature in both th images

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use ROIs(Region of Interests) to specify each component then compare each ROIs from Origin to a new image, It should be easier to handle big images with multiple components.